# Bootstrap sticky footer code clash between height and padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I'm attempting to add the sticky-footer.html example into my bootstrap project.
however there is a clash of code in the body class that is screwing with my layout.

In my page code with bootstrap responsive fixed navbar uses:

```
  body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
}
```

In the sticky footer example it uses:

```
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  }
```

At the moment I have both body tags included in my css. Everything is working except on the desktop page widths versions, with the current css below I get a sticky footer with extra depth, and the page has a vertical scroll bar even though it does not need one? And it's all to do with this body tag clash and the extra `60px`.

```
  /* Sticky footer styles
  -------------------------------------------------- */

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {         
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -190px;
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,
  #footer {
    margin-top:20px;
    height: 190px;      
  }
  #footer {       
background-image:url(assets/img/herringboneLight.jpg);   
  }

  /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {

    }
  }

 body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
 }
```

Cheers
Alex

Comment: Put all of your body into a div tag and pad that instead would be my attempted solution.

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what's causing the problem; namely, the two clashing body tags. Why not play with them a bit and update your question with how you tried to fix it, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which browsers you are trying to support, but a CSS3 solution ([actually in IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)) I believe would be to change the `box-sizing` on `body`:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    -moz-box-sizing: padding-box; /* or border-box */
    -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box; /* or border-box */
    box-sizing: padding-box; /* or border-box */
}
```

This should cause the `height: 100%` to include the `60px` in the overall amount. It is working in Firefox so, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GBKF/) has scroll bars, [this one does not](http://jsfiddle.net/2GBKF/1/).

Comment: @user2004211: As a new user here, let me remind you that you should "accept" this answer by clicking the "check mark" under the vote number to the left. Also, if you found it particularly useful, you should additionally upvote the answer.